# Check if cron ran and have fallback

Tags: mysql, php, cron

I have written a realtime bus tracking program that runs a cron every minute to check the service of the bus. In order to remove some server resources I am going to be creating an instance on PHPfog then croning it there. My Question is what's the best way to know if the cron failed and if so then run the local server copy as a backup?

Comment: Why not check the results right inside crontab? Like, `if /usr/bin/check_bus; then local_copy; fi` ?

Comment: how is it real time if you run it every minute via cron?)

Answer (score 0):

I redirect both of stdout and stderr to a log file:

```
*/15 * * * * /usr/bin/php bus_tracking.php >> /var/log/bus_tracking.log 2>&1
```

and use Nagios's [check_logfiles](http://labs.consol.de/lang/de/nagios/check_logfiles/) plugin to monitor this log:

`command[check_bus_tracking]=/usr/bin/sudo /usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_logfiles --tag=bus_tracking --logfile=/var/log/bus_tracking.log --criticalpattern="error|Permission denied" --warningpattern="warning"`

You can also write an [event handler](http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/eventhandlers.html) to run the local server copy.

Comment: okay, now say that to a 5 year old :)

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Just that some of that was over my head. I see that Nagios is a server monitor that i'm assuming I'd need to install first.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it would be easier to use a service like https://deadmanssnitch.com. If your cron job fails you'll get an alert. This way you'd only have to dig through log files when it really matters—after a failure.